# after login through django social all_auth after redirect to webpage again webpage is refereshing when clicking on to it

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i have used social django all_auth for login through gmail and it redirects to the page where i want but i am facing a problem after login through gmail it again refereshing the webpage and i want to perform two operations through textarea first it redirect me to gmail login after login when it returns back to the same page it takes input to it but whenever i click it refereshes the webpage and input not shows just bacause of that refereshing.
here is myhtml code"

```
 <form id="new_user_form">  
     <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google'%}">
     <textarea style=" width: 500px;
     border: 2px solid #333;
     padding: 15px 10px;"placeholder="Add Your Comment"></textarea></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Visit your html page
2. Click link on page to GoogleAuth
3. Redirect to the same html page, now with the ability to enter a comment. But if you click (add comment?) after logging in, the page just refreshes?
   I think what you need are a few things:
   whatever view is rendering this html template needs to be handling the backend logic to
4. modify the rendering of the template to hide the add comment option before authentication
5. if the user is authenticated, show the textarea.
6. Handle form submission, insert the fetched contents of the form into the html (to 'display' the comment on the page, and re-render.
   Do you have the views.py code?